# Algorithm or library/software for standardizing color between two digitized works based on reference color separation/grayscale?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, colors, photo

I have two digitized works (think old manuscripts) that were individually photographed directly beside standard separated colors/grayscale reference strips. You can see [examples of the references here, e.g. Kodak Q-13](https://library.brown.edu/dps/curio/category/imaging/technical-guidelines/).

Even though they should be very close, my two digitized images are markedly different in color, due to ambient lighting and/or camera differences, as shown by the reference colors looking different even though identical standard color strips were used.

I am working on finding a way to adjust color in one image to match the other, to the point that the reference color strips end up as a very close match on a digital display, which will be my measure of success.

Should this be treated like a multivariable optimization problem? What are the variables, and what is the optimization function? Here are some candidates for variables to adjust:

- R, G, B
- Brightness adjust
- Contrast adjust
- Gamma adjust
- (Other level adjustments?)

Alternately, is this an already solved problem off the shelf, and I'm not not knowing where to look?

Comment: A general approach is to define three multivariate polynomial of a low degree (quadratic or cubic) and perform fits using the reference colors and their theoretical RGB values (or the RGB values taken from one reference image). The model being linear, you can use least squares easily. Then apply the model to recompute every pixel.